# Cstring input using get() c++

Tags: c++, cstring

Trying to write the following function but confused, as get() only reads in the first character?

Write C-string's chars to the screen one char at a time.

```
void writeString(const char*)
```

Rule:
cannot use `[]`.

Hints:use `put();`

make use of `'\0'` – but don't write it out.

Comment: I think others have done this same homework. You should try searching for it.

Comment: Why are you worrying about `get` and reading in, when you're supposed to *write* and the hint says to use `put`? Both of those are the opposite of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need a simple loop to output the string. Something like this perhaps.

```
void writeString(const char* str)
{
    while(str++ != '\0') put(*str);
}
```

The `while(str++ != '\0')` will iterate over the string buffer pointed to by `str` and output each character. It also increments the str pointer to the next character and checks for null terminator (`'\0'`).